# How to UPDATE table in psycopg2

Tags: python, sql, psycopg2

```
def GetUpdate():
    enter = input("What attributes do you want to change ? ")
    select,p_id =  input("Please enter your attributes separated by space: ").split()
    try:
        cur.execute("UPDATE  Diary SET %s = %s where diary_id = %s",(enter,select,p_id))
        #cur.execute(sql, (select, p_id))
        con.commit()
        print("Updating in table Diary is completed successfully")
    except (Exception, ps.DatabaseError) as error:
        print(error)
```

I want to make update function as you see I have 3 input parameters, first is what column in db I want to change .But 2,3 parameters is update parameters. When I'm trying run this code I got error. He takes my first input not as parameter, but as a Variable(string)

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text in the question. Better remove the "try" and the except-block for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cur.execute("UPDATE  Diary SET ❌%s❌ = %s where diary_id = %s",(enter,select,p_id))
```

You can't use a bind variable to set a tablename or column name or the like.  I.e. you can't compose/build a query from binds, only use binds to substitute in sql arguments.

For example, see [Oracle doc](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bind.html) (first one I found citing this):

> Bind variables can be used to substitute data, **but cannot be used to substitute the text of the statement. You cannot, for example, use a bind variable where a column name or a table name is required. Bind variables also cannot be used in Data Definition Language (DDL) statements, such as CREATE TABLE or ALTER statements.**

Sure, you could compose the query as

```
qry = f"UPDATE  Diary SET {enter} = %s ..."
cur.execute(qry,(select,p_id))
```

but that's a massive security risk of the [sql injection kind](https://xkcd.com/327/) and designing around how to safely take in user-supplied params to build into a safe sql query goes beyond answering your asking why this error was happening.